# pyCharm: force import lines to not get grayed out

Tags: python, pycharm

I want to make an other modules method available.

```
from other_lib import foo_method
```

Since `foo_method` is not used in this file, it grayes out this line.

Is there a way to stop pyCharm from doing this?

Comment: Do you mean comment this line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The feature giving this kind of information is called `Inspections` on Intellij platforms. In this case, it seems that `Optimize imports` has been grouped under `Unresolved references` (at least in Pycharm 4 CE).

You can disable this inspection once for all, yet be aware that in-code inspections of unresolved references (eg. attributes), will also be disabled. There are at least two ways:

1. With the keyboard : put the caret on the problem and press `Alt + Enter` then `Optimize imports | Disable inspection`.
2. From the menu : `Preferences | Editor | Inspections` where you can disable `Unresolved references`.

If you'd rather keep this inspection since it has other useful usages, and just disable it for a couple of statements, you can `Alt + Enter | Optimize imports | Suppress for statement`.

Comment: thank you. "Alt + Enter | Optimize imports | Suppress for statement" worked. I asked myself how this should work first. But it is easy: the string "# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences" gets inserted before my line. Works good. Solved the problem. Thank you.